# Android - Why Doesn't Android Obey The Pythagorean Theorem?

Tags: android

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 that is 5.0 inches diagonally. I confirmed this both by looking this up on the internet and measuring my phone with a ruler.

By programmatically getting my phone's width and height in pixels, I got the width to be 1080px and the height to be 1920px. My phone's density is 480dpi, which is xxhdpi.

Using this convertor (https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/), 1920px is 4.00 inches and 1080px is 2.25 inches, all at xxhdpi.

Using the Pythagorean Theorem, the diagonal line in inches for my phone should be approximately 4.59 inches, not 5.00 inches.

The Pythagorean Theorem doesn't rationalize Android's sizing of several of its virtual devices as well. Why is this not adding up? Am I doing the calculations wrong?

Comment: Your assumption that `dp == dpi` is flawed

Comment: Hey, [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9500_galaxy_s4-5125.php) says your phone's density is ~441 which brings your phone's diagonal length to `~4.99309`

Comment: @Shaishav I don't know how I'm making this assumption. When the density is xxhdpi, 1920 pixels takes up 4.00 inches and 1080px takes up 2.25 inches. I'm sort of lost here.

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding you incorrectly but, `_dpi`s are buckets and when you want to do precise pixel based calculations you should look at the absolute pixel density.